# How to create an IF-ELSE statement if there are two similar MAX value, hence find the MIN value from the database

Tags: c#, sql, max, min

I have four column in my database, 'UniqueID','Exam', 'Percent1' and 'Time1'. I am able to display the MAX value from the database easily, hence able to get the the best 'Exam' result.

But now I encounter a problem where if there are similar MAX value, which 'Exam'to choose. Hence I though if this problem occur, I would pick the MIN from the 'Time1' column, which is the same row as the MAX value. But I am not sure how to do this.

I tried something like this, but unfortunately there was an error. Any suggestions or hints is extremely appreciated. Thank you

```
var userID = "hello";
    string maxnum, name;

    string SqlString = "SELECT max(Test3)from Table2 WHERE Test1 = @ID AND min(Test4)";

    using (objCon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectString))
    {
        using (objCmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, objCon))
        {
            objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
            objCon.Open();

            maxnum = objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            Label1.Text = maxnum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the value you get from the query in all cases is just the `max`, if you have many the same max values, it doesn't matter, it just picks the right max for you, so how could you choose the right row? at least you have to select more columns to see the difference

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Test4 is your Time1 column;

```
string SqlString = "SELECT Top 1 max(Test3), Test4 
                    from Table2 WHERE Test1 = @ID  
                    Group By Test4 
                    Order by Test4"
```

Comment: If i would like to display the Test 4 value, which is the Time1 also, how should I add the parameter? Do I use ExecuteScalar just like how to display the MAX using variable maxnum also? I am not sure what I should type?

Comment: try this;
`string[] result=maxnum.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
Label1.Text =result[0];
string Test4 =result[1];`

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly does this part do

    `string[] result = maxnum.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });`

and is this the correct way to get the data of max test3 and its Test4?

`objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
                objCon.Open();
                maxnum = objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               
                string[] result = maxnum.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' }); 
                Label1.Text = result[0]; 

                string Test4 = result[1];
                Label2.Text = Test4;
                
                
            }`

Comment: Yes, since `ExecuteScalar` returns the 1st row, you just need to split the result to retrieve them column by column. And `result[0]` will contain the 1st value, that is the value of `max(Test3)` and similarly, `result[1]` will contain second column, taht is Test4

Comment: I got an error that says it is out of bounds

**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

shouldnt I use, executereader instead of executescalar? as execute reader will take the whole row of data?

Comment: If you wish, in either way, the query will return only 1 row. if you're getting out of bound, means the SELECT is not returning 2 value. result[0] should retrieve 1st column and result[1] for second column of the fetched row

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub request like this

```
SELECT max(Test3)from Table2 WHERE Test1 = @ID AND 
Test4 = select(min(Test4) from Table2 where Test1 = @ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:

```
string SqlString = "SELECT top 1 * from Table2 WHERE Test1 = @ID order by Exam desc, Time1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to answer by using this code:

```
string SqlString = "SELECT Top 1 Test3, Test4 from Table2 WHERE Test1 = @ID Order by Test4 ASC, Test3 ASC";

using (objCon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectString))
{
    using (objCmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, objCon))
    {
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
        objCon.Open();

        OleDbDataReader reader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = reader["Test3"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = reader["Test4"].ToString(); 
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    objCon.Close();
}
```

Thank you everyone for taking your time to help me